# When is classical electromagnetism applicable?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, approximations, models

I'm currently studying intermediate level classical electromagnetism and I'm wondering, given that quantum mechanics is the suitable theory for describing the behaviors of microscopic systems, when is classical electromagnetism applicable? I'm really confused by all those physical theories and it seems like every theory describes a different world.

Answer (score 1):

**When is classical electromagnetism applicable?**

Quantum mechanics provides the most accurate description, but it will contain some variable(s) that, when taken to a given limit, will reproduce classical electromagnetic experimental results.

The short answer to your, rather general,  imo, question, depends on how accurately and precisely your measurements can be made.